# how to implement mapAccumM?

Tags: haskell

I want `mapM` over something that is traversable while passing an accumulator. I came up with:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Traversable
import Control.Monad.State

mapAccumM :: (Applicative m, Traversable t, MonadState s m)
             => (s -> a -> m (s, b)) -> s -> t a -> m (t b)
mapAccumM f acc0 xs = put acc0 >> traverse g xs
  where
    g x = do
      oldAcc <- get
      (newAcc, y) <- f oldAcc x
      put newAcc
      return y
```

How can this be done without `State` monad?

Comment: You could use `StateT` and `runStateT` within your function, without requiring the outer monad to be a state monad...

Comment: to be clear, do you want the same type with with a `Monad m` restriction instead of `MonadState s m`?

Comment: ChrisTaylor: yes I want Monad m

Answer (score 2):

roconnor answered this for me on #haskell

this solves my problem but notice that accumulator is returned in the second element of the tuple instead of the first

```
mapAccumM :: (Monad m, Functor m, Traversable t) => (a -> b -> m (c, a)) -> a -> t b -> m (t c)
mapAccumM f = flip (evalStateT . (Data.Traversable.traverse (StateT . (flip f))))
```

or to also return the accumulator:

```
mapAccumM' :: (Monad m, Functor m, Traversable t) => (a -> b -> m (c, a)) -> a -> t b -> m (t c, a)
mapAccumM' f = flip (runStateT . (Data.Traversable.traverse (StateT . (flip f))))
```

Comment: Not sure if a state monad transformer count as "without State monad" ;D