# how to implement mapAccumRM?

Tags: haskell

I asked a similar question before ([how to implement mapAccumM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652809/how-to-implement-mapaccumm)).

I need the one which folds from the right as well (`mapAccumR`):

```
mapAccumRM :: (Monad m, Traversable t) 
           => (a -> b -> m (a, c)) -> a -> t b -> m (a, t c)
```

Is there a simple implementation for this?

Comment: `Traversable` doesn't have a notion of "right" vs. "left" associativity; and `Foldable` doesn't have a notion of structure-preserving operations. So you will almost certainly need either a separate instance of `Traversable` that visits elements in the correct order, or a separate typeclass that mixes the notions of visitation order and structure preservation. I would make this an answer, except "you can't" is a pretty strong claim that I don't really know how to prove. But I'll be happy to discuss the suggestions I've made here further if either of them seem palatable.

Comment: Okay, I just went ahead and discussed both suggestions anyway. ;-)

Comment: This comment was enlightening, thank you. I accepted your simpler answer because it's the one which is easiest for me to implement because my data structure has a reverse function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to define new instances of `Traversable` that use the ordering you like. For example, for lists, one might simply define a new type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Traversable

newtype BackwardsList a = BackwardsList [a]
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Functor, Foldable)

instance Traversable BackwardsList where
    traverse f (BackwardsList xs) = BackwardsList <$> go xs where
        go [] = pure []
        go (x:xs) = liftA2 (flip (:)) (go xs) (f x)
```

In ghci, we can see the difference between this and the standard instance:

> ```
> > runState (traverse (\_ -> modify (+1) >> get) "hello, world!") 0
> ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],13)
> > runState (traverse (\_ -> modify (+1) >> get) (BackwardsList "hello, world!")) 0
> (BackwardsList [13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],13)
> ```

This approach is fairly simple; however, it requires a new type (and the associated newtype wrapping/unwrapping garbage) for every new traversal order that you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

One could consider defining a new type class for ordered traversals. Let's see one way this might be done. We'll need a little prelude:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types, TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Traversable
import Data.Tree
```

Most Haskell data types can be viewed as fixed-points of polynomial functors; and the functors that they are fixed-points of are good descriptions of the "spine" of the data structure. We'll abuse this idea to give a concrete way to encode the ordering that should be used during traversal. The class itself looks like this:

```
type Order t = forall f a. Applicative f => Spine t (f a) (f (t a)) -> f (t a)

class OrderedTraversable t where
    data Spine t :: * -> * -> *
    otraverse :: Applicative f => Order t -> (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

Notice that the type of `otraverse` looks just like the type of `traverse`, except that it now takes an extra ordering argument. The ordering argument is, in a sense, variadic; since different data types have different numbers of values/children at various places in their structure, and the ordering may care about all of them. (Of special interest is here is the technique of using rank-2 types to prevent an ordering from observing "too much" about a data structure: it can't use special facts about a given instance of `Applicative` or given kind of element to decide how to traverse a spine, only decisions based on the shape of the spine are allowed.) Let's see a simple example, for lists:

```
instance OrderedTraversable [] where
    -- Cute hack: the normal presentation for the spine of a list uses both
    -- a `Cons` and a `Nil`; but parametricity says the only thing an
    -- `Order []` can do with a `Nil` is `pure []` anyway. So let's just
    -- bake that into `otraverse`.
    data Spine [] a r = Cons a r
    otraverse order f = go where
        go []     = pure []
        go (x:xs) = order (Cons (f x) (go xs))
```

Compare with the implementation of `Traversable` for lists in the standard library (I have taken the liberty of expanding the definition of `foldr` to make it more closely match the code above):

```
instance Traversable [] where
    traverse f = go where
        go [] = pure []
        go (x:xs) = (:) <$> f x <*> go xs
```

As you can see, the primary difference is that we have abstracted which function to use to combine `f x` and `go xs`. We can recover the standard `Traversable` instance with a "head-first" order. There is also a "last-first" order; and these are basically the only two orders that make sense for lists.

```
headFirst, lastFirst :: Order []
headFirst (Cons fx fxs) = liftA2       (:)  fx fxs
lastFirst (Cons fx fxs) = liftA2 (flip (:)) fxs fx
```

In ghci, we can now see how they differ:

> ```
> > runState (traverse (\_ -> modify (+1) >> get) "hello, world!") 0
> ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],13)
> > runState (otraverse headFirst (\_ -> modify (+1) >> get) "hello, world!") 0
> ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],13)
> > runState (otraverse lastFirst (\_ -> modify (+1) >> get) "hello, world!") 0
> ([13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],13)
> ```

To give another example, here is how you might use this class with rose trees:

```
instance OrderedTraversable Tree where
    data Spine Tree a r = SNode a [r]
    otraverse order f = go where
        go (Node x ts) = order (SNode (f x) (map go ts))

-- two example orders for trees
prefix, postfix :: Order [] -> Order Tree
prefix  list (SNode fx fts) = liftA2       Node  fx (otraverse list id fts)
postfix list (SNode fx fts) = liftA2 (flip Node) (otraverse list id fts) fx
```

Note that there are actually infinitely many "good" ordering functions for rose trees; two that are particularly likely to be what you want are included above.

Comment: What exactly are "polynomial functors" ? Google only yields incomprehensible (to the mere mortal) category theory. For example, is `data Spine [] a r = Cons a r` a polynomial functor?

Comment: @user2407038 Polynomial functors are the ones that are constructed from products and sums of the given type (and nothing else -- so no fixed points). `data Spine [] a r = Cons a r` is a polynomial functor (and in fact a polynomial bifunctor). You might like the paper [Functional Programming with Bananas, Lenses,
Envelopes and Barbed Wire](http://eprints.eemcs.utwente.nl/7281/01/db-utwente-40501F46.pdf).

Comment: @user2407038 However, I wasn't being quite precise. The truth is it doesn't matter whether the functor is a polynomial or not; the only important thing is that the fixed point of the functor is (isomorphic to) the type you want to traverse.